# quote_from_bytes() expected bytes when passing headers

Tags: python, typeerror

I have this request in my Python application:

```
get_bkt = json.loads(str(client.get_bucket(bucket, headers={"client-ip": "192.168.1.100"})))
```

It gives me this error:

```
TypeError('quote_from_bytes() expected bytes')
```

This is the beginning of the function I'm calling:

```
def get_bucket(self, bucket, **kwargs):
    """
    Returns metadata for the specified bucket.

    Returns metadata for the specified bucket.

    :param str bucket: Name of a bucket.
    :param dict headers: A `dict` containing the request headers
    :return: A `DetailedResponse` containing the result, headers and HTTP status code.
    :rtype: DetailedResponse
    """
```

Is there something wrong with the way I'm passing the headers? If so, how do I fix this?

**Additional Info**

I've changed it to this based on a few things I read online:

```
headers = {"client-ip": "192.168.1.100"}
get_bkt = json.loads(str(client.get_bucket(bucket, *headers)))
```

Now I get this error:

```
TypeError('get_bucket_config() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given')
```

As with the previous error, I'm not sure what it's about. I guess it's telling me I'm passing one too many args but I don't believe this to be the case. Am I wrong?

If I then change

```
get_bkt = json.loads(str(client.get_bucket(bucket, *headers)))
```

to

```
get_bkt = json.loads(str(client.get_bucket(bucket, **headers)))
```

I don't seem to get the error. I'm not sure this is correct though.

Comment: You're not showing us how it's calling `quote_from_bytes()` or what it is supposed to do.

Comment: I'm not sure where that's coming from. I think my issue now is the `ypeError('get_bucket_config() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given')`

Comment: We still have no idea how the code you posted ends up calling these functions, or with what values, or what they might be supposed to do. Voting to close as unclear; perhaps review the guidance for how to [edit] your post into a [mcve].

Comment: @tripleee I'm quite possibly wrong but I have a feeling this has something to do with the way I'm calling `get_bucket` and how I'm passing my parameters.

Comment: It's not at all impossible but we cannot debug code we cannot see.

Comment: `get_bkt = json.loads(str(client.get_bucket(bucket, **headers)))` is the correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I needed:

```
get_bkt = json.loads(str(client.get_bucket(bucket, **headers)))
```